# Filtering dictionary In Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, nsdictionary

hello I am am new in Swift and trying to implement a search bar on table view. so I followed one tutorial on Youtube and implement the tutorial correctly. But I have some problems working with my data. As in tutorial the data was in `NSArray` and mine is coming from web service and its in `NSDictionary`

So My data is saved in NSDictionary and If I have to access the variables I do this

```
cell.countryNameLabel.text = (((dict["\(indexPath.item)"] as?NSDictionary)!["Countries"] as?NSDictionary)!["name"] as?NSString)! as String
```

okay In tutorial He has done something like this

```
 var filterTableData = [String]()
   var tableData = ["one","two","three"]


 func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
       filterTableData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

        let searchPredict = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
        let array = (tableData as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredict)
        filterTableData = array as! [String]
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

and Now I want to know how can I implement this as I have data stored in `NSdictionary` and variable is **dict**

Comment: When you get the dictionary from your web service load it into an array of structs. Dictionaries are unordered and don't work well with tableviews

Comment: Parse your dictionary into custom objects. Don't work with dictionaries, work with objects.

Comment: @Paulw11 what do you mean by unordered? mean data don't pops up sorted

Answer (score 1):

You can store the keys of the dictionary to an Array object
and use it in the function.

```
var filterTableData = [String]()
var tableData = Array(dict.keys)
```